# Why is my datetime parameter for a stored procedure being rejected?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc

I’m working on a Java server app which uses Spring 3 and C3P0 to access a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database, using version 3.0 of Microsoft’s JDBC 4 driver.

I have a sproc which has an input defined like so:

```
@modifiedAfter datetime = NULL
```

I’m using Spring to construct a call to this sproc.

I’m constructing a [MapSqlParameterSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/MapSqlParameterSource.html) to contain my parameters:

```
MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
in.addValue("modifiedAfter", "2011-01-01T00:00:00", Types.TIMESTAMP)
```

But when I execute the call:

```
this.sprocCall.execute(in);
```

I get this:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

…and I have no idea why.

I’ve tried a few variations on adding the parameter, such as passing it in as a `Date`, or specifying it as a `VARCHAR`, or not specifying the type — none of them work.

I’m beginning to suspect that the problem might be related to Spring. I wrote a little Groovy script to try to isolate the problem, and this works just fine:

```
dt = new DateTime("2012-02-01T00:00:00") // Joda DateTime
println sql.rows("exec spMySproc @modifiedAfter=${Sql.TIMESTAMP(dt.toString())}")
```

…but when I try the equivalent approach with `MapSqlParameterSource`, I get the above error.

At this point, I’m stumped.

Here’s the top of the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call spGetPoliciesCatalogPaged(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:952)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:985)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:368)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:342)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:164)
```

… which is followed by some of my classes, then this:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4762)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1682)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:955)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:2859)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.processResultSet(JdbcTemplate.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractReturnedResults(JdbcTemplate.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$5.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:995)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:936)
    ... 68 more
```

I tried updating to the latest version of `spring-jdbc`, 3.1.1, but it did not help.

I’d appreciate any help at all!

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: Have you tried string instead of Types.TIMESTAMP? I think Types.TIMESTAMP format cannot be converted in sql server.

Comment: TIMESTAMP in SQL Server has absolutely nothing to do with date or time.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo, @Aaron: I’m not using the SQL Server `timestamp` format. I’m using the JDBC TIMESTAMP format. As per [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878.aspx) the JDBC driver maps the JDBC TIMESTAMP format to the SQL Server types `datetime` and `datetime2`. Also, the above Groovy script which uses JDBC TIMESTAMP works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A co-worker of mine figured this out. It turns out that I had jumped the gun by blaming Spring and/or the Microsoft SQL Server driver. The problem was indeed an error when converting a character string to a date/time — but it wasn’t a problem directly with my parameter, it was a problem with a query that was being run by the dynamic SQL generated by my sproc, *if* I passed in this parameter.

The problematic code looks something like this:

```
IF @modifiedAfter IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'AND mytable.ThingLastUpdated > @modifiedAfter'
END
```

Once the dynamic SQL contained in `@SQL` was actually executed, the contents of `@modifiedAfter` — a perfectly valid `DATETIME`, sent in from my Java code with no issues at all — were compared with the contents of `mytable.ThingLastUpdated` — which was a `VARCHAR` column which meant that SQL Server had to convert its contents to `DATETIME` so that they could be compared to `@modifiedAfter` — but not all values in `mytable.ThingLastUpdated` could be successfully converted, hence the conversion error being thrown.

The fix I decided on was to change the type of `mytable.ThingLastUpdated` to `DATETIME`, and do any needed conversion at insertion time, which I think will be more efficient than doing so at query time.

Lesson learned: if a SQL problem isn’t in *my* Java code, it’s probably in *my* SQL — not in Spring or a JDBC driver. PEBKAC.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem in and was looking @ MSDN and looks like Sql-Server 2005 had a bug with precision conversion. Supposedly the version you are using has bumped up the precision 100ns. Will it be possible verify if the time-stamp precision. Here is the link for the discussion: [Sql Server Conversion error](http://connect.microsoft.com/sql/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=355655)

Comment: My problematic example code has the value hard-coded: `in.addValue("modifiedAfter", "2011-01-01T00:00:00", Types.TIMESTAMP)` so you can see there’s no data at a precision level which a standard SQL Server DateTime wouldn’t be able to represent.

Comment: in.addValue("modifiedAfter", "2011-01-01T00:00:00", Types.String), how about that one? Because the value "2011-01-01T00:00:00" is no problem to be converted in sql server.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo `Types.String` does not exist. You can see a list of all the JDBC types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html). I tried `Types.VARCHAR` and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

How about passing the input as String/varchar and then converting it to datetime in the sproc?

Comment: While I think that would probably be a serviceable workaround, and I appreciate the help, workarounds are not what I’m looking for — I want to understand why my code, which _should_ work, isn’t working.

Answer (score 1):

This error is defenitely not a SQL problem bacause it converts that string "2011-01-01T00:00:00" to datetime successfully. The sql parameter type you have declared is of type TIMESTAMP and you are passing a string. I think that is where it fails to convert.

Try declaring the sql parameter type as string or varchar instead of TimeStamp.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I already tried that. It doesn’t work.

Comment: Do you mean as the value or as the specified type? To be clear, I’m pretty sure the problem here is with Spring — I know very well that the semantics of what I’m trying to do should be supported by JDBC and MSSQL. Anyway, I have tried various combinations of values and specified types — Java `Date` objects, `Types.VARCHAR`, etc. At this point I believe that Spring is introspecting the sproc, seeing that the parameter is declared as `DATETIME`, and trying to coerce the value to something compatible — and failing, for some reason. I guess I’ll have to dig into Spring’s source code…